Round numbers and use units in apache echart
Struggling with these in my echart:

round numbers on Y axis
convert numbers on Y axis to short number ( 10000000 => 1M , note: the chart does not look nice with high numbers )
convert units in X axis to seconds ( 0.00 => 2ms,  2.0256 => 2,05s. note: these are buckets )

I am trying to create a similar chart to Duration distribution chart in https://grafana.com/media/products/cloud/application-observability/service-overview-1.png
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    axisTick: {
      show: false
    },
    data: [0.002, 0.004, 0.128, 0.512, 1.0256, 2.0512, 5.1],
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow'
    }
  },
  grid: {
    top: '4%',
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [1204546.1235, 200456.315311, 1504561.11, 8046456, 7456456.654, 1146540.6484868432, 134560.1],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ]
}

https://jsfiddle.net/o3dxqm8p/
Thanks

I dont really understand your problem with rounding / converting values. You have full control over what you pass to echarts and can precompute everything thats neccessary.
That beein said, the solution to all your problems seems to be the formatter function. See below for an example converting yAxis values.
Example:
yAxis: {
  axisLabel: {
    formatter: (value) => value / 1000000 + ' Mio'
  }
},
xAxis:
  axisLabel: {
    formatter: (value) => {
      if (value < 1) return value * 1000 + ' ms';
      else return value + ' s';
    }
  }
}


Yes, but units don't scale, so this would be weird for values lower than 1Mio, especially in the tooltip. For xAxis, look at Duration distribution graph https://grafana.com/media/products/cloud/application-observability/service-overview-1.png, there are both ms and seconds.

This is just an example. Since the formatter takes a function you can apply more complex logic if neccessary.  I adjusted the example for the xAxis.
